# using curl to get from one webpage to another involving javascript

Tags: php, javascript, curl, screen-scraping

I have webpage1.html which has a hyperlink whose href="some/javascript/function/outputLink()"

Now, using curl (or any other method in php) how do I deduce the hyperlink (of http:// format) from the javascript function() so that I can go to next page.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd have to scrape the JavaScript. Figure out where the function is and see what URL it's using.

Sometimes `http://` is omitted for links that are on the same page, so that won't be a good search reference.

At this point the only valuable thing to do is to try and understand the JavaScript code yourself, and once you find the *link* you could use **regex** to filter the result programmatically with PHP.

```
preg_match("/url + \'\/apples.html/g", "blah blah var javaScriptVar= url + '/apples.html';", $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no straight forward way. There are very few to zero libraries which can perfectly do what you require. I think http://www.dapper.net/ is something close to what you want. I am not sure if its the ideal solution. Dapper.net will help you parse text and links and would probably also handle javascript.