# Unable to get html links with cURL

Tags: javascript, php, html, curl

I am trying to get the links from a website. When I try to connect through the terminal I get this message: "You have to turn on javascript and cookies support in browser to visit this site". I have tried many different codes here in stackoverflow and all around google. None are working the way I would like it to. None of them is getting any data from this website that I try to get data from. Other sites work.

```
    <?php

function get_url( $url,  $javascript_loop = 0, $timeout = 5 )
{
    $url = str_replace( "&amp;", "&", urldecode(trim($url)) );

    $cookie = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "" );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );    # required for https urls
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 10 );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $response = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ( $ch );

    if ($response['http_code'] == 301 || $response['http_code'] == 302)
    {
        ini_set("user_agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");

        if ( $headers = get_headers($response['url']) )
        {
            foreach( $headers as $value )
            {
                if ( substr( strtolower($value), 0, 9 ) == "location:" )
                    return get_url( trim( substr( $value, 9, strlen($value) ) ) );
            }
        }
    }

    if (    ( preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\.replace\('(.*)'\)/i", $content, $value) || preg_match("/>[[:space:]]+window\.location\=\"(.*)\"/i", $content, $value) ) &&
            $javascript_loop < 5
    )
    {
        return get_url( $value[1], $javascript_loop+1 );
    }
    else
    {
        return array( $content, $response );
    }
}
$test = get_url('http://livefootball.ws');

print_r($test);

?>
```

If I switch out the URL to some other website, I get the result, but with this website it is not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting  `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` also pointing to your `$cookie` and make sure you have permissions for the server to be able to write to that file.  That may take care of the cookie problem.  But as far as the Javascript problem, I think you're out of luck.

[How to simulate that JavaScript is enabled with PHP Curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4258292/how-to-simulate-that-javascript-is-enabled-with-php-curl)

Comment: I have managed to get the output by cURL from the terminal of my mac. So it means that it should work without the Javascript problem. But still not working with the php version of cURL, even if I put up a CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE.

Comment: Okay, I just tried connecting to the website `livefootball.ws` with cURL and got this error message `CURL Error (http://livefootball.ws): Failed connect to livefootball.ws:80; No error`.  So then I tried connecting to it in my browser and got `Unable to connect - Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at livefootball.ws.`  Check to make sure the URL is correct and if so, that it is accessible.

Comment: The URL is working in my browser, weird that it's not working for you?